# Is it possible to configure DNS rules that are only valid inside of a VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, docker

I have an internal website and a few microservices that are only accessible on a VPN (which is set up using WireGuard running in docker).

Currently, users access these services by using the private/local IP address of the servers assigned by the VPN server and optionally adding a port number, e.g. `<server IP>:<server port>`.

Is it possible to create fully qualified domain names that resolve to the location of these services ONLY when users are connected to the VPN?

I *could* create a regular DNS rule mapping some FQDN to the public IP address of the internal website server, but not all of the servers have unique public IP addresses.

Can I somehow run my own DNS server on the VPN that takes priority over public DNS servers? I imagine that this way, if I have specified that `www.google.com` should resolve to `192.168.0.1`, users would end up at that address rather than the real google.com site. If I hadn't specified that rule, I would want users to fall back to a public DNS service.

Is this possible? (or bad practice?)

Hopefully, that makes sense. This is my first question on StackExchange :)

Comment: Have you looked at adding `--add-host` to your `docker run` invocation, or `extra_hosts:` if you're using docker-compose? ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076194/using-add-host-or-extra-hosts-with-docker-compose))

Comment: What I'm saying is that you could add this to the VPN container.